# How to remove white lines when plotting multiple subplots in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I run the following code, even though running `ax.axis('off')` white lines appear.

```
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (6, 6)
fig=plt.figure()

for i in range(121):
    ax=plt.subplot(11,11,i+1)
    ax.axis('off')
    ax.imshow(weights[0][:,-i].reshape((28,28)),cmap='Spectral_r')
    ax.axis('off')
    plt.subplots_adjust(hspace = 0,wspace=0)
```

result:

[subplots with white lines even when axis is set 'off'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewolt.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The white lines are the background you see through at the spaces between the plots; it has nothing to do with the axes lines.

To make sure to have no space between the plots you can either let them be scaled automatically, 
`imshow(..., aspect="auto")`, or you set the subplot parameters such that there would not be any spaces left, e.g. in your case of a square figure with equal number of subplot rows and columns,

```
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.15, right=0.85, bottom=0.15, top=0.85, hspace = 0, wspace=0)
```

Comment: What confused me was the strange pattern in which the lines appeared, did not seem very regular.

Comment: If the spacing comes out to be less than a pixel, it will of course not always occur. E.g. if spacing was 0.66 pixels, it would occur only for 2 out of three boundaries.